# How to submit a GET request to get order information using UFT

Tags: uft-api

I am using sample flight application to practice API testing. I have created an order 93. I am trying to retrieve the details of the order no using GET request thru API layer. Below are the steps I have taken and I getting an error "Incorrect number format. Order number expected."

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to get the order details using GET request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what API you're interacting with, but if it follows some traditional REST principles, your request should probably look like this instead:

```
http://localhost:8000/HPFlights_REST/FlightOrders/93
```

This is under the assumption that the error returned is because the REST service is expecting the URL to adhere to the following schema:

```
http://localhost:8000/HPFlights_REST/FlightOrders/{OrderNumber}
```

Where `{OrderNumber}` is a purely numeric field (i.e., without `OrderNumber=...`).

Hope this helps